# Abstract class & method Java

Tags: java, abstract-class

I have an abstract generic class `Class1` with a method `A`.
A second class `Class2` extends from this `Class1` and implements a method `B`.
Is it possible to call the method `A` to build the method `B` ?

```
public static int B() {
    Object o = A();
    return 0;
}
```

I have the error : `non-static method A() cannot be referenced from a static context`.

The Class1 :

```
public interface Class1<T extends Object, ID extends Serializable> {

    public T A();
}
```

the Class2 :

```
public interface Class2 extends Class1<MyEntity,Long> {

    public static MyEntity B() {
        MyEntity o = A();
        // some works
        return o;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post more code for everyone here to understand your problem?

Comment: delete the `static` in B() or declare A() as `static`..., but before [take a look here](https://www.google.es/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=java%20tutorial%20classes%20and%20objects)

Comment: As the error said, your method A() is not static, and therefore canno't be called from a static method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invoking non static method from static method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952160/invoking-non-static-method-from-static-method)

Answer (score 0):

No, non-static methods can make reference to static methods because there will always be one copy that belongs to the class, but static methods cannot make reference to non-static as the class containing it may not have been initialized.

```
public static void hello(){
        hi(); //ERROR!
    }
    public void hi(){
        hello();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to instantiate an object from Class1:

```
public static int B() {
    Class1 object1 = new Class1();
    Object o = object1.A();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Right, but doing so he doesn't use the inheritance betweend Class2 and Class1

Comment: I can't because Class1 is abstract too !